# How does manage.py work?

Tags: python, django

I just installed django and I'm doing the tutorial on their website.

I'm following their instructions on command line and they're working, but I'm wondering why?

For instance, you can access the command 'manage.py startapp xyz' and it would create a package, but when I look into manage.py, it only contains the following code (added by django, I didn't touch manage.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "DjangoProject12.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I don't see any method for startapp in manage.py or anywhere else. I'm not sure if this is django specific or if there is some fundamental gap in my python knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: did you look at the `execute_from_command_line()` code?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I'm running these commands not through command line, but through eclipse's pydev's django plugin. I put in the command and get as output: Finished "C:\Users\zyz\workspace\DjangoProject12\src\manage.py startapp zxz" execution.

Comment: Eclipse just hides the details from you. In reality it still invokes manage.py from command-line-like environment (don't know the details, sorry), so manage.py performs exactly as if it is launched via command line

Comment: @monkut, yes I did. What I wasn't understanding is that sys.argv just passes through what's in commandline as a string, I wasn't seeing 'startapp' anywhere, and that was confusing me as I thought it was a method that I could ctrl+F. I just needed to dig deeper into django.core.management package, as Pieters suggests.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to look in the [`django.core.management` package](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/core/management); the [`execute_from_command_line()` function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/87bb746ea6bb4bf6fb9f87065d5daaca857a130c/django/core/management/__init__.py#L416) accepts the `sys.argv` command line parameters and takes it from there.

When you enter `manage.py startapp xyz` on the command line, `sys.argv` is set to `['manage.py', 'startapp', 'xyz']`.

These are handed off to a [`ManagementUtility` instance](https://github.com/django/django/blob/87bb746ea6bb4bf6fb9f87065d5daaca857a130c/django/core/management/__init__.py#L184), which has a [`.execute()` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/87bb746ea6bb4bf6fb9f87065d5daaca857a130c/django/core/management/__init__.py#L334) to do the actual parsing.

The whole `django.core.management` package is modular; the [`.commands` sub package](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/core/management/commands) contains the various standard commands for the `manage.py` tool. [`django.core.management.commands.startapp`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/startapp.py) handles the `startapp` subcommand, for example.